# Вирутальные функции

Tags: c++, наследование, виртуальная-функция

```
class A
{
private:
 virtual float sum() {...}
};

class B : public A
{
  float get_value();
  void set_value();
private:
 float sum() override{
  return value
 }

 float value;  
}

class C : public B
{
  C() : B() {set_value(1);}
}
```

Есть std::vector a. Там содержатся как объекты типа A так и C. И есть std::vector b. Там содержатся как объекты типа B так и C. При вызове функции sum из вектора a или b для объекта C, вызывается A::sum. При вызове функции sum из вектора b для объекта B вызывается B::sum.

Мне нужно чтобы в первом случае вызывался B::sum.

Comment: `vector` является гомогенным контейнером, то есть может содержать элементы одного и того же типа. Соответственно вам придется добавить один уровень перенаправления, то есть хранить не объекты, а указатели на базовый класс.

Comment: *"Есть std::vector a. Там содержатся как объекты типа A так и C."* Не содержатся. Если попытаться поместить `C` в `std::vector<A>`, то в вектор попадет копия не всего объекта, а копия подобъекта `A`, который в нем находится.